# Pure CSS float with alignments and nested structures

Tags: html, css, scope, css-float

We have a Javascript generated HTML template, and for it have multiple CSS layouts, from which we generate a PDF.

Desired output:

[image]

- the same color blocks are siblings,
- the big purple one contains the red ones.

the content in them are dynamic, so they can shrink and grow in height.

position: absolute is out of the question, because in that way i can never have the parent container know the absolute element height.
floats maybe?

created a pen for it:
  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaGEzN

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.container-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  display: inline-block;
  order: 2;
}

.details {
  display: flex;
}

.seller {
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-top">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="seller">
        <p>seller details</p>
        <p>seller details</p>
      </div>
      <div class="client">
        <p>client details</p>
        <p>client details</p>
        <p>client details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-bottom">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, I was going to bring the code of your Codepen demo into your question but then I saw the amount of SEO spam that was littering your content and decided not to, so instead: pointers: **1.** reduce your demo code to the absolute minimum amount necessary so that we can reproduce the problem (think: "*[mcve]*"); **2.** post that code in your question (don't just link to it and definitely don't expect us to follow links around the internet for the benefit of helping you); **3.** don't put spam (SEO or otherwise) in your demos (or, ideally, your production site).

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind posting an updated, or additional, image that shows how you want the minimised HTML/CSS to appear? And, incidentally, you say that "*the same color blocks are siblings*" but you show a purple element within the outer purple element; is that a sibling of the 'container' or should it be red (and a sibling of the 'contents')? (Or - genuinely - should I consider an optician?)

Comment: your codepen code different and your desired output completely different

Comment: I have done header part follow this code https://codepen.io/RammmohanBandaru/pen/dKpJgY?editors=1010 and  in same way develop remaining part

Comment: its the sibling